# Is $R \setminus P$ a multiplicative subset?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, notation

> Let $S$ be a subset of the ring $R$; we say that $S$ is multiplicative if
>
> (a) $0 \notin S$,
>   (b) $1 \in S$, and
>   (c) whenever $a,b\in S$, we have $ab \in S$.
>
> We can merge (b) and (c) by stating that $S$ is closed under multiplication, if we regard $1$ as the empty product.
>
> Here are some standard examples of multiplicative sets.
>
> 1. The set of all nonzero elements of an integral domain.
> 2. The set of all nonzero elements of a commutative ring $R$ that are not zero divisors.
> 3. $R \setminus P$, where $P$ is a prime ideal of the commutative ring $R$.

I think 3 is not a correct  example  as $R \setminus P$ is an integral domain and has zero element $P$. It should be $R \setminus P$ except $P$. Is it right?

Comment: A good exercise to see the link between prime ideals and multiplicative sets: Prove that an ideal $I$ of a ring $R$ is a prime ideal if and only if $R\setminus I$ is a multiplicative set.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The notation $\,R\backslash P\,$ means exactly "all the elements in the set $\;R\;$ except those belonging to $\;P\;$" .

I think you confused this with the **quotient ring** $\;R/P\;$ ...

Comment: @DonAntonio: This is emphasized by the fact that the *correct* LaTeX symbol is `\setminus` :-)

Comment: Indeed @ZevChonoles , yet the resulting symbols are extremely alike: $$R\backslash P\;,\;\;R\setminus P$$ It's almost the same with \backslash and \setminus